# How to select which one to show in case of dual video in .mp4 file?

Tags: surfaceview, android-mediacodec, output-buffering, mediaextractor, input-buffer

I'm using surfaceView where i'm rendering the video. I have a .mp4 file with video/hevc and video/avc. I made two threads such that they are extracted, decoded and rendered to the surface though the surfaceView.
i can choose which video to show in the surface by changing this line in the thread:

```
 decoder.configure(format, null, null, 0);
```

to

```
 decoder.configure(format, surface, null, 0);
```

But how to do this dynamically on the fly with a click of a button?

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting Android version since M, you can set the surface on the fly by using 
[MediaCodec.SetOutputSurface(Surface)](http://www.iut-fbleau.fr/docs/android/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#setOutputSurface(android.view.Surface))
Note that for avoiding decoders concurrence on the same surface, a (only?) solution (bad?) is to use another hidden surface and pass it to the first decoder before setting your desirated surface to the second one

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment, can you post an example of the usage of that.

Comment: I did this by rendering the two videos in two separate surface view and then hiding one of it by using .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: Yes, you can do this, but to avoid using another SurfaceView, you can use a Surface like I mentionned above